# jQuery Submit Form onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to automatically submit a form using jQuery when an input is changed.

The input in question is a date picker and I need it to submit once somebody has made a selection.

```
<form id="select_date" name="select_date" method="POST" action="about.php?date-yes">
<input type="text" id="widgetFieldInput">
<input name="select_date" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#widgetFieldInput').change(function(){
       $('#select_date').click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 23):

Use the following jQuery snippet:

```
$("#widgetFieldInput").change(function() {
     this.form.submit();
});
```

Comment: What sort of datepicker are you using?  You need to share some code.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the [datepicker from jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) you can use the [onSelect event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) to fire custom code once a date has been picked:

```
$('you-date-input').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      // form submit code
   }
});
```

Comment: I am not using a datepicker fomr the jQuery UI :/

Comment: So is it a plain input field then, or are you using some kind of other datepicker component?